# how to check request come from parent window for child window

Tags: javascript

Please help I have develop two web pages.I want to check for open the child window. that come from parent window or direcltly copy paste the url of the page in javascript.

Comment: I don't care too much about getting accepted but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.opener
```

should contain something(a window-object) if an window is a child-window of another(opened using window.open() ) .

So you have to check  `window.opener` to see if a window is a child-window.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Page1.html and Page2.html, Page2.html can know if it was opened from within Page1.html by two ways:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof window.opener != "undefined")
        alert("I was opened from within " + window.opener.location.href);
    else if (document.referrer)
        alert("You came here from " + document.referrer);
</script>
```